# Storing all the values in column of a CSV file to a variable

Tags: python, csv

I have read the values from the Items.csv file and stored them in the dictionary items. I want to extract the values of C1 in the CSV file and assign them to a variable c1 for mathematical calculations. However, when I try to do it the following way, it just stores all the values in index [0] of the items[keys] rather than the whole column of C1. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.

```
import csv


file = open('Items.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
items = dict()
headersRead = False
headers = []

for row in reader:
    if headersRead == False:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            items[row[i]] = []

        headers = row
        headersRead = True

    else:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            items[headers[i]].append(row[i])

for key in items:
    if key == 'Item':
        continue
    c1 = float(items[key][0])
    c2 = float(items[key][1])
    c3 = float(items[key][2])
    constant = float(items[key][3])
```

This is the CSV file I am working with.

```
Item,C1,C2,C3,Constant
Guitar Hero,-0.1111,0,-0.2,10
iPhone 7,-0.1,-0.2,-0.33333,3
iPhone SE,-0.889,-0.23,-0.5,2
Star Wars,-0.0778,-0.373333333,-0.5,4
Markers,-0.667,-0.488333333,-0.65,3
Avengers,-0.556,-0.603333333,-0.756667,5
Elf on the Shelf,-0.04,-0.718333333,-0.863334,1
Pool Cue,-0.334,0,0,9
Tire Repair Kit,-0.223,-0.948333333,-0.076668,6
Silly Putty,-0.112,-0.063333333,-0.183335,1
Nike,-0.123,-0.178333333,0,5
```

I want the values for the c1 to be values of key C1 from the items dictionary read in from Items.csv file. Therefore, the values of c1 should be -0.1111, -0.1, -0.889, -0.0778, -0.667, -0.556, -0.04, -0.334, -0.223, -0.112, -0.123

Comment: What do you want to do when all the values are stored in `items` dictionary? What is your goal? There might be a better data structure depending on how you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `csv.DictReader` to read your rows as dictionaries, then update that row to convert the floats for the numeric values and append it to a `list`, eg:

```
import csv

with open('Items.csv') as fin:
    rows = []
    csvin = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in csvin:
        row.update((k, float(v)) for k, v in row.items() if k != 'Item')
        rows.append(row)
```

`rows` will then be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much. But, if I must have to read the values from CSV like the way I did, What should I do?

Comment: @PeldenKinyak could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70239992/edit) your post to include the desired output for the data given?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has all the values of C1 stored as strings in an array in the items Dict  : items['C1'].

c1AsFloats = map(lambda x: float(x), items['C1']) would give you an array of floating point numbers that you could then treat mathematically.

Note that in the last for loop of your code, the variables c1, c2, c3 and constant take on the first four values of items[key]. For example, when the variable key is 'C3', the variables c1, c2, c3 and constant take on the first four values of items['C3'] : c1 = '10', c2 = '3', c3 = '2' and constant = '4'.

Answer (score 0):

If your end goal is to store the values in C1 to a variable for calculation, you can access that using your dictionary `items`

```
items = {'Item': [], 'C1' : [], 'C2' : [], 'C3' : [], 'Constant' : []}
import csv
with open('Items.csv') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(f_csv)
    for row in f_csv:
      items['Item'].append(row[0])
      items['C1'].append(float(row[1])) 
      items['C2'].append(float(row[2]))
      items['C3'].append(float(row[3]))
      items['Constant'].append(float(row[4]))
print(items['C1']) #the variable that would hold the C1
```

which will give the output that you expect

```
['-0.1111', '-0.1', '-0.889', '-0.0778', '-0.667', '-0.556', '-0.04', '-0.334', '-0.223', '-0.112', '-0.123']
```